# rEFInd Shows No Boot Options

Tags: uefi, efi, refind

The grey screen with  the rEFInd Boot Management  banner comes up but with no entries. Computer is a  Dell Inspiron 7573. I've had rEFInd working successfully on a self-built desktop and a 2014 MBP and have no idea what could possibly be causing this. I have Windows 10 and Arch currently installed and can boot them with manually added efibootmgr entries and I could (and probably will) use GRUB2 but I'd love any insight as to why this is happening.

Comment: Encountering the exact same problem with the same setup (albeit different hardware: HP). Did you ever figure this out?